# How to get current user ID in SSMS from Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, ssms

I have a program in Visual Studio that loads table data from SSMS. Right now, it's hard coded in to load specific tables no matter who logs in.

In SSMS, I have tables of college classes. When a user logs in, I want to run code in Visual Studio to insert the classes they've taken (located in SSMS) into tables in Visual Studio.

**The root of my question is: How and in which program do I basically code "user with (current ID) has logged in. Get their data from SSMS and put it in the tables.**

You don't have to answer the latter part necessarily but I'm really struggling with getting first part. Getting the persons ID who's logged in.Is it **SCOPE_IDENTITY**? Is it **@@IDENTITY**? Trying my best to understand [this microsoft doc on scope identity.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql)

Courses:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/E34GW.png

Users: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxFWv.png

Info (loads at top of program): https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMdlA.png

Comment: The logged in user id is not SCOPE_IDENTITY nor @@IDENTITY. However, it is your application, you should know how to identify the logged in person. Your question is unclear, your users don't run Visual Studio so can you describe your app?

Comment: It's a degree reporting program. (This is for fun here, don't worry about security, etc). When a user makes an account, they will select what classes they've taken. A table will be made in SSMS for that user that includes all the classes they've taken. I want to load the data in SSMS into a DataGridView (table) in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with identity. Identity describes auto-incrementing columns on a table.

The easiest way to accomplish this would be with a parameterized stored procedure. When your user logs in, you execute a procedure that will return all the class info for that user ID. If they are each going to be a user/login in SQL Server, you can use

```
SELECT DATATBASE_PRINICAL_ID()
```

to get their id, but chances are that will not align with what is in your table data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll look into that! Quick question. If I want to get users data from a table in SSMS, should I try to grab the users ID in SSMS or an arbitrary value such as a username?

Comment: @ColtonHorvath That depends. Add a sample of what your data looks like in your post.

Comment: I've added the images. Basically, a new table will be created based on the classes a user selects and says they've completed. When they log in, **their** classes table will load into different parts of the program. I'll do the same with the Info table as well. Which is why I was asking if I should just have the users make usernames instead of me trying to get their logged in ID from SSMS.